# How to extract substring in python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have a string such that `this is title [[this is translated title]]` and I need to extract these two subfields. `this is title`, `this is translated title`

I try to use regex but couldn't get it done.

```
def translate(value):
    # Values are paseed in the form of 
    # "This is text [[This is translated text]]"
    import re
    regex = r"(.+)(\[\[.*\]\])"
    match = re.match(regex, value)
    # Return text
    first = match.group(1)

    # Return translated text
    second = match.group(2).lstrip("[[").rstrip("]]")

    return first, second
```

But this gets failed. when the string is "simple plain text"

Comment: What you have seems to work.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a simple way without using regex

```
def trns(value):
    first, second =  value.rstrip("]]").split("[[")
    return first, second
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the regex `r'((\w.*)\[\[(\w.*)\]\]|(\w.*))` yields **this is title** in `group(1)` and **this is translated title** in `group(2)` so your code should be

```
def translate(value):
    # value = "This is text [[This is translated text]]"
    import re
    regex = r'((\w.*)\[\[(\w.*)\]\]|(\w.*))'
    match = re.match(regex, value)
    result = [x for x in match.groups() if x and x!=value]
    return result if result else value
```

this returns as you expected.

For testing your regular expressions you can use [this.](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I think this get failed with value="this is only text"